# How to use UIMenuItem for UIMenuController?

Tags: iphone

I planned to customize the menu item pop-up menu in my `UIWebView` but I don't know how to do this.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Also check out https://github.com/steipete/PSMenuItem if you want to use UIMenuItem with blocks.